# Why is it "I can make it come true" instead of "I can make it comes true"

Tags: tense, grammaticality

Since "it" is singular, why is the correct form "I can make it **come** true" instead of "I can make it **comes** true"?

Comment: "You can't make him **be** good." 'Make' here is operating as a causative verb, with essentially SVO+Vinf ... pattern. [John] [makes] [Jill] [work] {on Sundays}. (There is also a modal, _can_, complicating the issue here.) Note that _be, work, come_ are the base form of the verb.

Answer (score 1):

Whether "it" is plural or not has no bearing on anything, because "it" is an object, not the subject.

And in fact whether the subject "I" is plural or not makes no difference either, because the conjugated verb in the sentence is the helper verb **can** (which, being one of the many "special" verbs in English, actually retains the same form for all conjugations).

**Make** is a bare infinitive and will always look like "make" in this sentence regardless of the count of the subject:

> I can make it.
> They can make it.
> She can't sing it.
> We can run it.
> You can see it.

In all those examples the second verb is the bare infinitive.

Comment: The OP's question is about "come", not "make". The answer is similar, but your examples address the rule of *base form after modal verb* rather than whatever grammar there is in "*make it **come** true*".